# Nestjs "nest start --watch" leads to strange Windows Visual C error

Tags: nestjs

I have hd NestJS working for quite a while now. I am running the newest stable NestJS release v.10.2.7.

Suddenly today the pnpm run dev (nest start --watch) resulted in a strange error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpUhZ.png)

Has anyone experienced something similar?

I am running Node v. 20.9.0 (64 bit).

I have tried several things. Re-installed the Microsoft Visual C++ 2017-2022 reditributable. I've changed the project into using npm instead of pnpm. Lastly I tried installing different node versions. Node version 18.10.0 and 18.16.0 and tried to use each of them in turn. I can run other script commands from the package.json scripts section e.g. "pnpm run node ./dist/main.js".

The nest cli is working in the project as I can generate resources.

Any ideas?

Thanks.